# How to Feed in the output of one LSTM along with Text into another LSTM in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to feed in the output of one LSTM layer into another LSTM layer, along with the text included for that layer. The text provided to the two LSTM's is different, and my goal is that the second LSTM improves its understanding of it's text based on what the first LSTM understood.

I can try to implement it in Tensorflow like this:

```
# text inputs to the two LSTM's
rnn_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, text_data)
rnn_inputs_2 = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, text_data)
# first LSTM
lstm1Output, lstm1State = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=lstm1, 
        inputs=rnn_inputs, 
        sequence_length=input_lengths, 
        dtype=tf.float32, 
        time_major=False)
# second LSTM
lstm2Output, lstm2State = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=lstm2, 
        # use the input of the second LSTM and the first LSTM here
        inputs=rnn_inputs_2 + lstm1State, 
        sequence_length=input_lengths_2, 
        dtype=tf.float32, 
        time_major=False)
```

This has an issue, since `rnn_inputs_2` size is of `(batch_size, _, hidden_layer_size)`, while `lstm1State` size is of `(batch_size, hidden_layer_size)`. Does anyone have an idea of how I can change the shapes to make this work, or if there is some better way?

Thanks

Comment: What is the interpretation of the `_` in the `rnn_inputs_2` shape?

Comment: @DavidParks It is the maximum length of the input sentence/sequence. So it is a fixed amount, like 100 for example.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused if so correct me. But based on what you're saying above I don't think you mean to add the hidden state to the `rnn_inputs_2`. I suspect you mean to concatenate `lstm1Output` with `rnn_inputs_2` which should both have the timestep dimension. If you want to feed the state of the first RNN to the 2nd RNN you should do that by specifying the initial state of the 2nd RNN (if you don't specify this the 2nd RNN will start with a default state of 0's). Am I on track here? A diagram of what you're trying to do might help, both in understanding and explaining.

Comment: I could concat `lstm1Output` with `rnn_inputs_2`, but I am unsure if this would do what I want. LSTM1 is given a sentence, which given that it understands it correctly, will help LSTM2 understand it's sentence. I try to find a way to provide LSTM2 information based on LSTM1's understanding. If I concat the outputs of LSTM1 with the input of LSTM2, will that provide LSTM2 an understanding of LSTM1? Will using the hidden state of LSTM1 in LSTM2 provide an understanding? I'm not really sure how to approach this, if you can explain the intuition behind your ideas a bit more, that would be great.

Comment: I see, you're interpreting the hidden state of LSTM1 as a sentence embedding (rightfully so). And you now want to pass that sentence embedding into LSTM2 as prior knowledge it can base its decisions on. Did I describe that correctly? If so then you seem to be describing an encoder/decoder model, with the addition of new inputs to LSTM2. If that's accurate, then my first approach would be to pass the hidden state of LSTM1 in as the initial state of LSTM2. That would be far more logical than adding it to the input of each LSTM2 time step.

Comment: You would have the further benefit of having an extra gradient path passing from LSTM2 through the state of LSTM1 back to LSTM1, so you would be training LSTM1 on not only the loss function for LSTM1, but also on its ability to provide something that LSTM2 can use to improve its loss function (assuming you train both LSTM 1&2 in the same `sess.run` iteration).

Comment: @DavidParks I see, thanks for your explanation. One of the things I didn't mention earlier was that sometimes LSTM1 will receive no input, and obviously since it's input is a sentence, LSTM1 will receive different input every time. Would this impact the error updates for LSTM1 and LSTM2? Also, this would mean that I can't use an encoder-decoder system, right? Otherwise what you are saying makes sense, I am running it now and will see if it helps my performance.

Comment: Another question, what if I wanted to introduce a LSTM3 who's output should also effect LSTM2. In this case, would I just sum LSTM3 and LSTM1 hidden state and set that as the initial state for LSTM2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're interpreting the hidden state of LSTM1 as a sentence embedding (rightfully so). And you now want to pass that sentence embedding into LSTM2 as prior knowledge it can base its decisions on.

If I described that correctly then you seem to be describing an encoder/decoder model, with the addition of new inputs to LSTM2. If that's accurate, then my first approach would be to pass the hidden state of LSTM1 in as the initial state of LSTM2. That would be far more logical than adding it to the input of each LSTM2 time step.

You would have the further benefit of having an extra gradient path passing from LSTM2 through the state of LSTM1 back to LSTM1, so you would be training LSTM1 on not only the loss function for LSTM1, but also on its ability to provide something that LSTM2 can use to improve its loss function (assuming you train both LSTM 1&2 in the same sess.run iteration).

With respect to the question:

> Another question, what if I wanted to introduce a LSTM3 who's output
>   should also effect LSTM2. In this case, would I just sum LSTM3 and
>   LSTM1 hidden state and set that as the initial state for LSTM2?

Summing sounds bad, concatenating sounds good. You control the hidden state size of LSTM2, it should just have a larger hidden state size.

And with respect to this question:

> One of the things I didn't mention
>   earlier was that sometimes LSTM1 will receive no input, and obviously
>   since it's input is a sentence, LSTM1 will receive different input
>   every time. Would this impact the error updates for LSTM1 and LSTM2?
>   Also, this would mean that I can't use an encoder-decoder system,
>   right? Otherwise what you are saying makes sense, I am running it now
>   and will see if it helps my performance

In this case, if LSTM1 has no input (and thus no output state), I think the logical solution is to initialize LSTM2 with a standard hidden state vector of all zeros. This is what dynamic_rnn is doing under the hood if you don't give it an initial hidden state, so it's equivalent if you explicitly pass it a vector of 0's.

Comment: If I pass in 0's to LSTM1, then LSTM2 will have an initialized state of all 0's right? So I don't need to do anything special for those cases where LSTM1 is not used, just pass in all 0's for that training/test example? Thanks for the answer, I will accept it soon.

Comment: Exactly. an initial state of all 0's is meaningfully different to the LSTM than an initial state given some embedded sentence representation. The network can learn to make use of it as it sees fit. Just make sure you're training all the LSTMs together in the same update step so that the gradient can pass through from the later LSTMs to the earlier ones. You may need a `tf.cond` statement to produce the zero vector if nothing was passed in for LSTM1 though.

Comment: I'm a bit confused why I would need a `tf.cond` statement since the LSTM state should automatically be 0 if I pass in 0's for all examples in the batch right? Or no?

Comment: If you're processing both LSTMs at the same time, and LSTM1 is processing an input, you will take the final hidden state of LSTM1 and pass it to LSTM2. If you don't have input for LSTM1, thus don't run the optimizer OP for LSTM1, you won't have the LSTM1 state computed and will need to use a 0-constant. That's where I see the condition.

Comment: In that case won’t the LSTM1 hidden state either not exist or be all 0’s since 0’s are passed in? I was able to run this experiment without a special tf.cond condition.

Comment: LSTM1's hidden state wouldn't be computed, which is undefined, which would throw an error if you tried to use it. That is not equal to 0. I'm confused as to how you achieved that. If you used LSTM1's hidden state, it must have computed it from something. Did you pass in 0's for the input to LSTM1 or something? That would allow it to compute LSTM1 (though not in a way you want it to).

Comment: Yeah, I did pass in 0’s as input. How would the LSTM state be computed then?

Comment: Then LSTM1 took 0's as input, and computed a hidden state. Since you probably didn't train it on 0-valued input the LSMT1 hidden state is presumably garbage. I suppose your network may be able to discern between a hidden state that evolved from 0-valued inputs in LSTM1 and one that evolved from real data, it is a learning algorithm after all, but it sounds like you're running a process you don't mean to.

Comment: You should not pass in a value for LSTM1 if you are not going to compute LSTM1. If you do that now you will encounter a tensorflow exception when the hidden state input to LSTM2 is not computable. The fix for that will involve a `tf.cond` statement I expect.

Comment: @DavidParks I am interested in this approach. Can you please refer me to study/reference where this approach is implemented? I tried to implement it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62034413/using-output-from-one-lstm-as-input-into-another-lstm-in-tensorflow) but not sure if this is correct or not.

Comment: I feel like I gained a lot from papers like this one: https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03044. It's not exactly what's going on here, but it helps elucidate the patterns being described. Sequence to sequence models have a lot of resources, I don't have one in particular in mind, but this is a good starter: https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-encoder-decoder-sequence-to-sequence-model-679e04af4346. @AtherCheema