# Using output from one LSTM as input into another LSTM in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I want to build an LSTM-based neural network which takes two kinds of inputs and predicts two kinds of outputs. A rough structure can be seen in the following figure.

[image: neural network structure]

The `Output 2` is dependent upon `Output 1` and as described in answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592134/how-to-feed-in-the-output-of-one-lstm-along-with-text-into-another-lstm-in-tenso), I have tried to implement this by setting the initial state of LSTM 2 from hidden states of LSTM 1. I have implemented this using TensorFlow using the following code.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True) # to suppress scientific notation while printing arrays

def reset_graph(seed=2):
    tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)  # tf.set_random_seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)

tf.__version__

seq_len = 10
in_features1 = 3
in_features2 = 5
batch_size = 2
units = 5

# define input data
data1 = np.random.normal(0,1, size=(batch_size, seq_len, in_features1))
print('input 1 shape is', data1.shape)

data2 = np.random.normal(0,1, size=(batch_size, seq_len, in_features2))
print('input 2 shape is', data2.shape)

reset_graph()

# define model
inputs1 = Input(shape=(seq_len, in_features1))
inputs2 = Input(shape=(seq_len, in_features2))
lstm1 = LSTM(units, return_state=True)
lstm1_out, lstm_h, lstm_c = lstm1(inputs1, initial_state=None)
dense1 = Dense(1)
dense1_out = dense1(lstm1_out)

lstm2 = LSTM(units)
lstm2_out = lstm2(inputs2, initial_state=[lstm_h, lstm_c])

dense2 = Dense(1)
dense2_out = dense2(lstm2_out)
```

The inputs to two LSTMs are not exactly same because some of the `Input 2` has nothing to do with `Output 1`, but `Output 2` is definitely influenced by `Output 1`. For example `Output 1` is water flow and `Output 2` is water quality, so water quality is influenced by water flow.

This code runs fine, but I am not sure if this code does what I intend it to do, i.e. the working of `LSTM 2` being influenced by the output of `LSTM 1`.

Please verify if the implementation and reasoning are right or wrong?

Comment: inputs1 is equal to inputs2? I see only one input, is it correct?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani They are different but not entirely. However, I have edited the question to make them different.

Comment: thanks... so in this way, there are 2 "branches". the way the two communicate is sharing the lstms states, is it correct? I say this because in the image the arrow seems to connect the dense1 with the lstm2

Comment: @MarcoCerliani The arrow shows the original intent of the network i.e. to make use of lstm1 outputs as inputs into lstm2 (along with inputs2). However, the answer to a similar question (linked in question as well) suggested that same can (or should) be done by setting initial state of LSTM. So my question is, does setting the initial state as I have done is correct? and does it serve the purpose i.e. I want LSTM2 to be influenced by output of LSTM1.

Comment: ok, so if you don't want to concatenate the output of lstm1 with input2 (as described in the solution you cited) sharing the states is what you need. otherwise, if you have one single input (as reported before the edit) you can stack the two lstm cells and produce 2 output at different levels (I can report a solution for this second scenario)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani For the second scenario, the inputs must be same but the inputs are actually not exactly same. There are input variables related to output2 which have nothing to do with output1. For the 1st scenario, I did not concatenate the two outputs to show that loss will be calculated from both outputs separately and their mean will be used as final loss for the network.

Comment: I have difficulty understanding why the inputs are the same but they are actually not exactly same hahaha (but I think it's because I don't know what you are doing). I didn't say to concatenate the outputs... I said to concatenate the output of lstm1 with input2 (as described in the question you reported) the outputs remain separated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214723/discussion-between-ather-cheema-and-marco-cerliani).

Answer (score 0):

> This code runs fine, but I am not sure if this code does what I intend
>   it to do, i.e. the working of LSTM 2 being influenced by the output of
>   LSTM 1.
>
> Please verify if the implementation and reasoning are right or wrong?

Yes, the implementation and reasoning are right. Passing the final state of LSTM1 as the initial state of LSTM2 creates the dependency you are looking for. However, I am not completely convinced of this solution. In order to LSTM2 be able to take into account output1 it's more natural to just concatenate output1 to the input2 and let LSTM2 learn to abstract features from [Input2, Output1]. But anyway, both solutions create the dependency between input2 and input1 your described.

The solution that concatenates the output of LSTM1 to input2 can be described like this:

As LSTM1 return a sequence (`return_sequence=True`) you can just concatenate the output of the LSTM1 `(seq_len, num_units)` to imput2 `(seq_len, in_features2)` resulting in `(seq_len, num_units + in_features2)`.

```
# define model
inputs1 = Input(shape=(seq_len, in_features1))
inputs2 = Input(shape=(seq_len, in_features2))

lstm1 = LSTM(units, return_sequences=True)
lstm1_out = lstm1(inputs1)

lstm2_input = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([inputs2, lstm1_out])
lstm2 = LSTM(units)
lstm2_out = lstm2(lstm2_input)

dense1 = Dense(1)
dense1_out = dense1(lstm1_out)

dense2 = Dense(1)
dense2_out = dense2(lstm2_out)
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Can you elaborate the advantage and/or possible disadvantage of this approach as compared to 'initial state sharing' method which I have tried to implement and has been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48601112/5982232)?

Comment: There is not a specific advantage in my opinion. Both solutions create a dependency between input2 and input1. I edited the answer trying to be a litle bit clearer.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `return_sequences` in the code instead of `return_state`? And since we want to feed output from LSTM1 as input to LSTM2, so wouldn't it be better to do this by using a single Dense layer, but first apply it on final outputs of LSTM1 to and then to apply it on all outputs of LSTM1 which can be concatenated with inputs2?

Comment: Yes, it should be return_sequences, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: I think it's better to use directly the output from the LSTM1 (without dense layer) because when you apply the dense layer you are removing the "sequence" nature of the input which I think could be interesting for the LSTM2. However, it depends on your data, so I will recommend you to try these different approaches and check which fits better for your problem.

Comment: By this approach, the input to LSTM2 would be dependent upon LSTM1 units and if e.g. we have 64 units in LSTM1, the input to LSTM2 would be `[batch_size, seq_len, inputs2+64]`. That means very large input to LSTM2 and 90% of which comes from LSTM1 alone.

Comment: Yes, it increases the input of LSTM2, whether it is bad or not depends. If  inputs2 is  128 and units are 64 is not too much. The approach to use depends on your problem. Unlucky, there is not a good approach for everything.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have not understood how does applying Dense on LSTM1 output removes 'sequencesness' from the data even when using with `return_sequences=True`. if `return_sequences` is True and we apply `Dense` to its outputs, we still get a sequence which has the same order.